# What is the significance of Application key in a Laravel Application?

Tags: php, laravel

from laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#configuration)

> Application Key The next thing you should do after installing Laravel
>   is set your application key to a random string. If you installed
>   Laravel via Composer or the Laravel installer, this key has already
>   been set for you by the php artisan key:generate command.
>
> Typically, this string should be 32 characters long. The key can be
>   set in the .env environment file. If you have not renamed the
>   .env.example file to .env, you should do that now. **If the application
>   key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not
>   be secure!**

What I know about application key is: If the application key is not set, generally I do get an exception.

- How do this random string help to secure the session?
- What are the other uses of this application key?
- If I use the same application key everywhere (like staging, production etc..) does it make the application less secure?
- what are some best practices for this key

Comment: please be kind to explain downvotes. so that I could delete this post if neccessory. thanks

Comment: *If I use the same application key everywhere (like staging, production etc..) does it make the application less secure?* I even reset staging key on every deploy.

Comment: well, why you do that? @Kyslik

Comment: So every session is invalidated :), besides that from `config/app.php`: *This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service...*

Comment: I don't know why downvote this is a very good question from what I know it's used in cookie encryption and session data encryption.May be it has some role in api security but i don't know I never tried to learn more about but now that you have put up this question I am curious

Comment: Take a look at this [general community question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4755/web-application-encryption-key-management).

Comment: @Viney no it is not used in API security if - we talk about using [Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport), package generates its own certificates as far as I know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is used in [`EncryptionServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php#L16-L30):

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('encrypter', function ($app) {
        $config = $app->make('config')->get('app');

        // If the key starts with "base64:", we will need to decode the key before handing
        // it off to the encrypter. Keys may be base-64 encoded for presentation and we
        // want to make sure to convert them back to the raw bytes before encrypting.
        if (Str::startsWith($key = $this->key($config), 'base64:')) {
            $key = base64_decode(substr($key, 7));
        }

        return new Encrypter($key, $config['cipher']);
    });
}
```

So every component that uses encryption: **session**, **encryption** (user scope), **CSRF token** benefit from the `app_key`.

---

Rest of the questions can be answered by "how encryption" (AES) works, open up [`Encrypter.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L82-L110), and confirm that Laravel uses AES under the hood and that the implementation encodes the result to base64.

An example using `tinker`:

```
➜  artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> encrypt('Hello World!')
=> "eyJpdiI6ImgzK08zSDQyMUE1T1NMVThERjQzdEE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYzlZTk1td0JJZGtrS2luMlo0QzdGcVpKdTEzTWsxeFB6ME5pT1NmaGlQaz0iLCJtYWMiOiI3YTAzY2IxZjBiM2IyNDZiYzljZGJjNTczYzA3MGRjN2U3ZmFkMTVmMWRhMjcwMTRlODk5YTg5ZmM2YjBjMGNlIn0="
```

> **Note**: I used this key: `base64:Qc25VgXJ8CEkp790nqF+eEocRk1o7Yp0lM1jWPUuocQ=` to encrypt `Hello World!`

After decoding the result we get (you can try decode your own cookie with session):

```
{"iv":"h3+O3H421A5OSLU8DF43tA==","value":"c9YNMmwBIdkkKin2Z4C7FqZJu13Mk1xPz0NiOSfhiPk=","mac":"7a03cb1f0b3b246bc9cdbc573c070dc7e7fad15f1da27014e899a89fc6b0c0ce"}
```

to understand above JSON (`iv`, `value`, `mac`) you need to understand AES:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

---

#### Good practices for an application key

- **do** store it in `.env` file only
- **do not** store it in `app.php`, in fact in any git tracked file
- **do not** change it unless you really want to

  - invalidate sessions/cookies (user logout)
  - invalidate password reset tokens
  - invalidate [signed urls](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#signed-urls)

> **Note**: Changing application key has no effect on hashed passwords since hashing algorithms do not require encryption keys.

Comment: really detailed answer

Comment: thank you for the obvious note. It wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: @senecaTheMeek I changed the wording to not include "obvious". Thank you.