# Encrypt in Rails, Decrypt in Laravel

Tags: php, ruby, laravel, encryption

I have a question about `Encrypt Decrypt in Rails` and `Laravel 5`

Case: 
I want to encrypt some data in Rails and data will be decrypted sometimes in Laravel.  I've already read how Laravel encrypts flow with `HMAC sha256, SAE-256-CBC` and do the flow in Rails. 
But unfortunately, Laravel can not decrypt

Here my code:

```
@cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
@key = ENV['LARAVEL_APP_KEY']

...

@cipher.encrypt
@cipher.key = Base64.decode64(@key)
iv = @cipher.random_iv
@cipher.iv = iv
encrypted = @cipher.update(PHP.serialize(string)) + @cipher.final

iv = base64_encode(iv)
encrypted = base64_encode(encrypted)
mac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), iv + encrypted, Base64.decode64(@key))

hash = { iv: iv, value: encrypted, mac: mac }
base64_encode(hash.to_json)
```

- The `APP_KEY` has already bee same between Rails and Laravel
- Expected result: Rails `Encrypt 1000`, Laravel will get 1000 too
- Real result: Rails `Encrypt 1000`, Laravel get the encryption *(ex: eyfasffksffadsfreqw)*

Please help! Many thanks!

Comment: Where's the decryption code?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the decryption code is used basic decrypt from laravel. Just like this decrypt($value);

Comment: I do not know about RoR but Laravel does also base64 on the result I write about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445420/what-is-the-significance-of-application-key-in-a-laravel-application/49445587#49445587

Comment: @Kyslik let me check the link. thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but still answering as it might help future readers just like me, Here is the working function, I only fixed the minor issue that you had in your code like sequence was wrong in OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest and changed base64 encode function that is not adding '/n' like Base64.encode64 (Your code helped me a lot to archive this faster).

```
def encrypt(value, key)
    @cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-cbc')
    @cipher.encrypt
    @cipher.key = @key
    iv = @cipher.random_iv
    @cipher.iv = iv
    encrypted = @cipher.update(PHP.serialize(value)) + @cipher.final

    iv = Base64.strict_encode64(iv)
    encrypted = Base64.strict_encode64(encrypted)
    mac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), @key, iv + encrypted)

    hash = { iv: iv, value: encrypted, mac: mac }
    return Base64.strict_encode64(hash.to_json)
end
```

Please note that here I am using the key that is not encoded and so I did not decode the key, so it's depends's on your implementation.