# Laravel 419 page expired while post request via form in blade

Tags: laravel, session, csrf, laravel-blade

I use Laravel 7. I have a page with scrf token send as a POST request in Blade form.

```
<form method="POST" action="some url">

    @csrf
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:25px;">
        <div class="form-group">
        
            <input name="keyword" type="text" class="form-control">
                       
            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">search</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

This line is in my head element:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

I have *file session* config. I already check *storage/framework/session* and it has permission to write files and new files created recently. When i put my url in csrf except array in *VerifyCsrfToken* Class, all things work just fine. I check my request and sure there is `_token` field right there. I'd read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp#:%7E:text=41%20Answers&text=The%20Session%20Expired%20or%20419,should%20be%20fine%20as%20well.) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445420/what-is-the-significance-of-application-key-in-a-laravel-application) too but answers didn't work in my case.

My from request sample:

[image: form request]

Comment: Did you set APP_KEY in your .env file?

Comment: Yup. I generate it with php artisan key:generate

Comment: Run ```php artisan cache:clear```

Comment: It didn't help. still 419 erorr.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583886/post-request-in-laravel-error-419-sorry-your-session-419-your-page-has-exp
Check out this post. There are many answers and solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I mention that link in my question.

Comment: Check your session driver and set it on database or redis

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad I changed my session to database(file => database) with no luck. I still have to add my path to verifycsrftoken exclusion array.  ):

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
{{csrf_token()}}
```

instead of

```
@csrf
```

Comment: Token is **exists** in my request bosy.